# Two side-by-side dodged barplots for both of my variables

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame like the one below...

```
Correlation_task_persistence <- c("0.40", "-0.46", "-0.24", "0.06")
Biv_A_task_persistence <- c("66%", "67%", "71%", "69%")
Biv_E_task_persistence  <- c("34%", "33%", "29%", "31%")
Correlation_activity <- c("0.33", "-0.59", "-0.10", "0.06")
Biv_A_activity <- c("40%", "65%", "70%", "97%")
Biv_E_activity <- c("60", "35%", "30%", "3%")
age <- c("30", "24", "18", "12")

df.new <- data.frame(Correlation_task_persistence, 
Biv_A_task_persistence,Biv_E_task_persistence,
 Correlation_activity, Biv_A_activity, Biv_E_activity, age )
```

I would like to like to reproduce bar plot figure below, which represents the data in the data frame above (ignore the error bars in the figure). Would appreciate any help on how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

suppressWarnings(
  df.new %>% 
    mutate(across(Correlation_task_persistence:Biv_E_activity, 
                  ~if_else(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x)) > 1,
                           as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x, fixed = TRUE))/100, 
                           as.numeric(.x)))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(age, contains("Correlation"))) %>% 
    mutate(Correlation = if_else(grepl("task", name),
                                 Correlation_task_persistence, Correlation_activity),
           final_value = Correlation * value,
           name = gsub("_task", "", name)) %>% 
    tidyr::extract("name", c("var","group"), regex = "(.*)_([^_]+)$") %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = age, y = final_value, fill = var)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~group)
)
```

[image]

##### Data:

```
df.new <- data.frame(Correlation_task_persistence = c("0.40", "-0.46", "-0.24", "0.06"),
                     Biv_A_task_persistence = c("66%", "67%", "71%", "69%"),
                     Biv_E_task_persistence  = c("34%", "33%", "29%", "31%"),
                     Correlation_activity = c("0.33", "-0.59", "-0.10", "0.06"),
                     Biv_A_activity = c("40%", "65%", "70%", "97%"),
                     Biv_E_activity = c("60", "35%", "30%", "3%"),
                     age = c("30", "24", "18", "12"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @M-- Very helpful. I modified the code to add an additional age (data for age 6), but the order of the bars gets screwed up (6 is displayed after age 30). I believe this is because it's lexographical order because my data is character. How can we fix the ordering of the ages such that it goes 6,12,18,24,30? I would also like to display the correlation (e.g. 0.40 for age 30 on top of the bar). How would we do this?

Comment: Nvm -- got it figured out!